# Why does my publish fail?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have published my project before with no problems, suddenly I get this error :

```
unable to add 'X' to the web site. unable to add file 'x' access is denied
```

When I delete X file and tried to publish again, I got the same error on another file..
I have no clue why it happend...

Can someone light my way ?

Comment: I've have this problem sometimes and I just restart my Visual Studio. Sometimes I build and rebuild back to back and that messes things up every once in awhile. Try closing the solution and reopening it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a permissions issue. What you have to do is grant "write" rights to yourself on the IIS directory (wwwroot by default). Then retry

**Update :** [How do I give ASP.NET permission to write to a folder in Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653722/how-do-i-give-asp-net-permission-to-write-to-a-folder-in-windows-7)

Comment: I am new to IIS.. Do you have a link to a simple instructions ?