# Content not displayed after migrate Website from IIS6 to IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, iis, asp-classic

New server is Windows 2008 R2 + IIS 7.5 There are websites working fine there, but were made using latest technologies (MVC4 etc). 
The website with issues is using Frm 3.5 and was working in Server 2003 IIS6.
I moved to the new server and looks like the CSS and JS are not displayed/working.
I tried all the other answers to similar issues in StackOverflow and MSDN (yes Static Content is enabled and MIME Types are correct).

Then I change the App Pool of this website to 2.0 Classic (was in Integrated) and is working fine. This is not a solution, sounds to me more a workaround.
What I am missing here? The differences between Classic app pool and Integrated does not mention anything in particular, apart that Classic works as IIS6.

PS: Same website in Server 2012 with IIS8 works fine with Integrated App Pool , I am about to get crazy !!!!

Please help !

Comment: Sounds like your IIS 7.5 is missing the StaticFileHandler. You can check this by opening the GUI and go to Handlers. Can you see if you find the StaticFileHandler there?

Comment: Thanks Saasen, there is a  StaticFile - * -  Enabled - StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule in both : server and website levels.

Answer (score 0):

Use IIS6 but your problem is CSS and JS are not displayed/working.

**Solution Is**

```
Running IIS6, I had luck adding permissions for the local computer user IUSR.

"Application pool" > "Advanced Settings" > "Identity" > "Custom account"

Set your website to "Applicaton user (pass-through authentication)" and not "Specific user", in the Advanced Settings.

Now give that IUSR_[identifier] the appropriate NTFS permissions on files and folders
```

[reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653722/how-do-i-give-asp-net-permission-to-write-to-a-folder-in-windows-7)

[other link](http://www.kbpublisher.com/kb/setting-up-folder-permissions-in-internet-information-services-(iis)_392.html)

Comment: Hi Denish, Website is with Applicaton user (pass-through authentication) and the IUSR_ has read-write permissions. I also tried with Full Control . Same results so far.  Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

Hey please try this ..... i hope it work.....

You may need to enable the IIS:ASP role service either in Server Manager or via the Web Platform Installer. Then once that is installed, you can create a new Application Pool with the following attributes:

Configure the App Pool ".Net Framework version" to use "No Managed Code"

Set the "Managed pipeline mode" to "Classic"

Set "Enable 32 bit Applications" to true, in the "Advanced Settings".

Set the "Identity" to "Network Service", in the "Advanced Settings".

Once you configure the new App Pool just set your site to run in the new App Pool in the Advanced Site Settings. This should get your site up and running on IIS 7.5