# Asp.net hosted(IIS) application does not accept the network shared folder path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory

I try to access the network shared file using asp.net application. But I got to access network shared file when I run a application. But i didn't able access the same shared file when i hosted in IIS. It did't accept the network shared folder path.

Answer (score 0):

try this all steps

```
Running IIS6, I had luck adding permissions for the local computer user IUSR.

"Application pool" > "Advanced Settings" > "Identity" > "Custom account"

Set your website to "Applicaton user (pass-through authentication)" and not "Specific user", in the Advanced Settings.

Now give that IUSR_[identifier] the appropriate NTFS permissions on files and folders
```

[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653722/how-do-i-give-asp-net-permission-to-write-to-a-folder-in-windows-7)

[other link](http://www.kbpublisher.com/kb/setting-up-folder-permissions-in-internet-information-services-(iis)_392.html)

Comment: Thank You for  your reference

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19830/How-to-Access-Network-Files-using-asp-net