# Saving image path on db and images into folder asp .net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image

I have issue in uploading images path into database and moving imagesg into folder, here is code:

```
public ActionResult UploadImages(
            HttpPostedFileBase formFilled,
            HttpPostedFileBase sixPics,
            HttpPostedFileBase buyerCNIC,
            HttpPostedFileBase sellerCNIC
            )
        {
            if (Session["user"] == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
            }

            CustomerDocumentImages dbCustomerDocs = new CustomerDocumentImages();

            string recieverName = Request.Form["RecieverName"];
            var allowedExtensions = new[] {
            ".Jpg", ".png", ".jpg", "jpeg"
            };

            dbCustomerDocs.FormFilledPhysicalPath = formFilled.ToString();

            var _formFilled = Path.GetFileName(formFilled.FileName); //getting only file name(a.jpg)  

            var ext = Path.GetExtension(formFilled.FileName);

            if (allowedExtensions.Contains(ext))
            {
                string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(_formFilled); //getting file name without extension  
                string formImage = name + "_" + DateTime.Now + ext; //appending the name with id  
                                                           // store the file inside ~/project folder(Img)  
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), formImage);
                dbCustomerDocs.FormFilledPhysicalPath = path;
                dbCustomerDocs.FormFilled = _formFilled;

                dbCustomerDocs.RecieverName = recieverName;

                try
                {

                    var currentAllotmentId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["AllotmentId"]);
                    var dbAllotment = db.Allotments.SingleOrDefault(i => i.AllotmentId == currentAllotmentId);
                    dbCustomerDocs.AllotmentId = dbAllotment.AllotmentId;
                    dbAllotment.IsCustomerDocsUploaded = true;

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please select valid allotment");
                }



                db.CustomerDocumentImagess.Add(dbCustomerDocs);
                db.SaveChanges();
                formFilled.SaveAs("~Images"+path);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.message = "Please choose only Image file";
            }


            return View();
            }
```

I have also used server.mappath but it woking fine on localhost but giving error on windows live server( on save as method ) , in case of combine.mappath works fine but not moving image into folder. please guide me, thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the error, you might be not have permissions to write files to that particular folder

Comment: this is not the case, i have everthing fine on localhost but giving error on live server ( save as )

Comment: i am saying about live server, you might not have write permissions to that particular directory on server

Comment: what is the best way to solve this issue becuase i have to solve it

Comment: @Ehsan have you any solution for this problem?

Comment: Here's several links on this site. http://stackoverflow.com/q/14653722/2030565 http://stackoverflow.com/q/16677887/2030565 http://stackoverflow.com/q/2532079/2030565 http://stackoverflow.com/q/5437723/2030565

Comment: I am confused please send me simple solution of my above problem

Comment: you would need to ask the person who manager webserver to set permission for application to write to that particular directory