# C# save a DataGridView Directory Comparison to CSV with special filename for C# Windows App

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview

I created a button that will allow a user to create a CSV based on a directory comparison. I compiled the code, and everything looks ok. I go to run the program, however, and I get a "Access is denied" error.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string csv = string.Empty;
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        using (var sfd = new SaveFileDialog())
        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string folderPath = fbd.SelectedPath;
            string filename = "DIR_" + (DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()) + ".csv";

                File.WriteAllText(folderPath + "DIR_" + (DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()) + ".csv", csv);

        }
```

Is there another way to save the datagridview into a CSV with the file extension give in the filename string?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have permission to write on the folder?

Try use `File.WriteAllLines`:

```
File.WriteAllLines(folderPath + "DIR_" + (DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()) + ".csv", csv);
```

Comment: How would I go about getting permission?

Comment: Also, the File.WriteAllLines didn't work sadly. String can't be converted to string[].

Comment: [To see permission folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653722/how-do-i-give-asp-net-permission-to-write-to-a-folder-in-windows-7)

Comment: Thank you! I'll see if this does allow me to work around the settings. Will this work with a Windows Application?

Comment: And it `System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"\test.csv");` `file.WriteLine(csv);`?