# Not able to upload image in my website folder

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I am trying to upload image in my website folder, but it is not uploading.
In my database I have "Photographs" column for storing image names and I store images in  images/1/.
Where images folder is at root level of website. On my localhost it is working perfectly fine, but same is not happening on my webserver.
If I skip photograph upload, all values are inserted properly. But otherwise nothing gets inserted.
 Below is my code:

```
       //this part works fine

        dr["EmailAddress"] = txtEmail.Text;
        dr["LoginEmailAddress"] = txtUserName.Text;
        dr["Password"] = txtPassword.Text;
        dr["IsAgent"] = rdAgent.Checked;
        dr["IsManager"] = rdManager.Checked;

        //below is code to upload photograph, where photograph is column name in 
        //database and working fine on localhost

       if(URLMessage.URLAction ==URLAction.update )
            dr["Photograph"] = WebHelper.SaveUploadFile(1, flPhoto, dr["Photograph"], lblRemove .Text .Equals ("Upload"));
        else 
            dr["Photograph"] = WebHelper.SaveUploadFile(1,flPhoto, dr["Photograph"], true);
```

My web.config is as follows:

```
        <appSettings>
        <add key="connectionString" value="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=dbABC;user id=abc; password=kashmirmed@123#;" />
        <add key="siteFileURL" value="abc.in/images/" />
        <add key="SiteFileFolder" value="abc.in\images\1\" />
        </appSettings>
```

Where abc.in is website name

Comment: can you give some detail about SaveUploadFile function..first

Comment: You probably just need to give the correct permissions to write in your /images folder, and it depends on how you set up your AppPool.

Comment: string path = Server.MapPath("images/") + FileUpload1.FileName;
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(path); try this two line this is basic code of file upload

Comment: also give detail about what error are you getting while try to upload file

Comment: @MANISHLANGA This is working for me in case of other website, so I am figuring I am doing something wrong on server end

Comment: @rikitikitik..it can be the reason, let me check

Comment: @MANISHLANGA I am not getting any error, file is uploading 100%, but then unable to write anything to database and also not saved in image folder, so I think it is persmission issue

Comment: yes then its 100% permission issue check http://forums.asp.net/t/1605243.aspx/1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532079/iis7-folder-permissions-for-web-application hope you will get ans from that link