# ASP.NET application cannot write to folder

Tags: asp.net, permissions, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a .net 2.0 application that I have migrated from a Windows Server 2003/IIS6 to Windows Server 2008/IIS7

This application needs to write to a folder in the public folders section on the server.  I have given full rights to:

- Everyone
- IUSR
- NETWORK SERVICE
- IIS_USRS

Still the ASP.NET app cannot write to the folder.  The folder is visible in IIS 7 Manager, and it exists on the file system.

Whenever I execute the part of the app that needs to write to the folder I receive the following error:

[image]

This worked fine on the previous server, but I cannot figure out how to get it to work on the new server.  Please advise.

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532079/iis7-folder-permissions-for-web-application

Comment: @NipunAmbastha I do not have the account `IIS AppPool\ApplicationPoolName` on the system.  IIS app pool runs under `NT Authority\Network Service`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In IIS7 is not like in previous version, you need to give permissions to the account under which the application pool is running:

See this:

[IIS7 Permissions Overview - ApplicationPoolIdentity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334216/iis7-permissions-overview-applicationpoolidentity)

And this:

[IIS AppPoolIdentity and file system write access permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437723/iis-apppoolidentity-and-file-system-write-access-permissions)