# how to host mvc4 website in local area network

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, shared-hosting

i am working in a mvc4  project and i want to publish the website in a local area network 
for this i have installed iis manager 8 and added site from

/mydocument/visual studio/project/myproject

set this path as default site in iis manager site

but i have error as

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to start monitoring changes to 'C:\Users\Neeraj\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\PSK\PSK' because access is denied.

Source Error: 


[No relevant source lines]
```

Comment: Take a look at this post... Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532079/iis7-folder-permissions-for-web-applicationdoes does that help you fix the problem?

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate for serverfault as it does not relate to programming.

Answer (score 1):

You could find how to fix "Failed to start monitoring directory changes" error message when you browse to an ASP.NET page at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317955.