# Connecting Azure SAP- or SharePoint-Connector to OnPremise fails

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, sap-dotnet-connector, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to connect Azure to our OnPremise-SAP-Installation. Our target: calling an RFC via SAP-Connector within a LogicApp.

What we did so far:

- Created a Relay-ServiceBus.
- Created a default SAP-Connector available in Azure Marketplace and inserted all required information including the ServiceBus-ConnectionString.
- For testing purpose: Created a new Windows Server VM onPrem:

  - Enabled IIS
  - Disabled Windows-Firewall
  - Installed SAP-Libraries required by the HybridConnector.
- Than we downloaded and installed the HybridListener on the Windows Server and entered the required ConnectionString.

Basically it was pretty much straight-forward according to this article:
http://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-integrate-with-an-on-premise-sap-server/

(Maybe except installing the SAP Libraries which is a bit weak documented..)

After all that installation process we went back into our Azure Portal. Suprisingly the SAP-Connector still told us: "**On-Premise Setup Incomplete**"

Our biggest problem: there are no other information available. Why is the Setup incomplete? Did we entered some wrong configuration or is there a network issue?

After some time we found out that we also need to open the following outgoing ports:

- 9350 to 9354
- 443

Unfortunately this was documented at a different place: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee706729.aspx

But the connection is still not working, same error as above: "**On-Premise Setup Incomplete**" And yes, we did reboot the IIS as well as the whole system.

My Question now: is there any possibilty to find the reason for this situation? A couple of weeks ago we had the same issue with an SharePoint-Connector which is still not running.

Is there any kind of HybridConnector-Logfile on the Server or something similar that helps us the figure out the real problem? Or maybe did someone had the same problem in the past and has some advice?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: Hybrid Connection is now online!

[image]

I just had to change writing permissions for the HybridListenerAppPool:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Aspnet_regiis.exe -ga "IIS AppPool\HybridListenerAppPool"
```

Solution found: http://forums.asp.net/t/1566987.aspx and [IIS7 folder permissions for web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532079/iis7-folder-permissions-for-web-application).

But it is still not possible to use the SAP Connector within a LogicApp:

[image]

After analyzing the Log of the AppService Gateway I found a hint telling me to look at the SwaggerFile of the SAP Connector:

[image]

I really do not understand why the HybridConnection is fine but there is still no Listener connected.

Comment: Troubleshoot this kind of requirement is not an easy task. Before use Azure, could you connect to your OnPremise-SAP using a console app for example? I would adopt another approach. First create a virtual network on azure and connect to your datacenter using a Site-to-Site VPN. After that, create a new extra small virtual machine and install SAP Connector in it. Then, create a console app to call your RFC.

Comment: @FiveT : please, let me ask you something: do I need to install SAP Connector listener on SAP Server machine or could I do that on a VM bridge?

Comment: It is possible to install the listener on seperate VM, yes. I can remember, a colleague had to install certain SAP libraries on that VM, which where required for the communication to SAP. As it is almost one year ago and it was just about testing new technology, unfortunately I cant tell you any more specific details. Good Luck, Thiago!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some firewall forensics, we actually figured out that there is some outgoing traffic on **ports 5671 and 5672**. If someone else faces the same problem, you need to open all the following outgoing TCP ports:

- 443
- 5671 - 5672
- 9350 - 9354

Unfortunatley it looks like this is not documeted at all.