# IIS on a virtual machine on a shared folder

Tags: windows, iis, webserver, virtual-machine, archlinux

I'm running Arch with a Windows 10 virtual machine and I'm trying to run an IIS server with an application in a shared folder. When I try to browse to it, I'm given a 500.19 error "cannot read configuration file". I know the application works under a normal Windows environment but I need the application to be in a shared folder under a virtual machine.

The shared folder is located in /home/hayden/virtual/shared.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: IIS does not support mapped drives at all, so you cannot use the typical shared folder provided by virtualization software. Move the files from shared folder to a local folder within the virtual machine and then set up your IIS web site to point to that local folder. Then you should get things done.

Answer (score 0):

Does IIS have permission to the folder? See [this post on how to do that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532079/iis7-folder-permissions-for-web-application)