# IIS AppPool isn't getting proper permission

Tags: iis-7.5

I have a website in IIS 7.5, I've followed and read about every topic I've found here and a few search result links.

My web needs to access a DLL on my `c:/folder/folder` drive.

I've granted full permission to "IIS_IUSRS" -- Didn't work, "IIS APPPOOL" -- Didn't work, "IIS APPPOOL\MyWebApp" (which converts to "MyWebApp" once I checkname it, also doesn't work.

Am I missing something here?

The most recent question I tried testing out was: [IIS7 folder permissions for web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532079/iis7-folder-permissions-for-web-application) but to no help in the end.

Comment: If anonymous authentication is used, you need to check what is the anonymous account in use, and then grant permissions to it (IUSR by default). I assume there are already tons of posts if you ask Google.