# How do I stop local kentico project from taking up port localhost:8080

Tags: visual-studio, localhost, port, iis-express, kentico

I installed Kentico and have been going through the tutorial. But I needed to work on another project and when trying to do so I was unable to as the Kentico project seems to be running on the localhost:8080 port.

I would like to restore localhost:8080 back to the way it was.

This is the error that I get when opening localhost:8080
[localhost error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruLJz.png)

I have tried to enable directory browsing and trying to stop the process running on localhost:8080 but they did not work.

Any help would be much appreciated if anyone has any suggestions or has had to deal with something like this before.

Answer (score 2):

In IIS you need to stop the site you were working on and start the other site you want to work on.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error snapshot (HTTP Error 403.14- Forbidden), it looks like its a access issue for your respective website virtual directory.

To overcome this problem you need to provide IIS user permission and the current system user permission to the kentico website folder and also make sure the path of your project in IIS pointing to Kentico Website solution until root folder where you have a web.config file.

How to give folder permission you can check on this reference link 
[IIS7 folder permissions for web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532079/iis7-folder-permissions-for-web-application)

Thanks and Regards

Nikhila Pocha

Answer (score 0):

You can change the port of the websites in the applicationhost.config file for IIS Express.
Mine is located under '%userprofile%/Documents/IISExpress/Config'.

From there you can search for the 'sites' node. Look for your website and change the port number in the following line:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
```